# Android CalenderView block few days from selecting

Tags: android, date, calendar, calendarview

I am using android `CalendarView` to choose days in first calendar view user will select **check-in date** and in next calendar view **check-out date** so every thing is working fine but if i check date as **10** in first calendar view then when we move onto to second calendar view there **till 10th date** it should not allow user to select after 10 user should select **check-out date**

```
calender = (CalendarView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);

    calender.setFocusedMonthDateColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTheme));
    calender.setUnfocusedMonthDateColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    calender.setSelectedWeekBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    calender.setWeekSeparatorLineColor(Color.GREEN);
```

the date we choose in the first calendar view should be the minimum date in next calendarview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. set string_date value according first calendar.

```
    String string_date = "24-November-2016";
    long milliseconds = 0;
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    try {
        Date d = f.parse(string_date);
        milliseconds = d.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    calender.setMinDate(milliseconds);
```